# Get variable inside DOM before DOM changes when clicking redirecting button

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I have been trying for so long to find a way to persist variables between page refreshes and different pages in one browser session opened from selenium python.
Unfortunately, neither storing variable in localStorage, sessionStorage or window.name doesn't work after testing so many times and research.

So I have resorted to a python script which continuously repeats driver.execute_script('return variable') and continue to gather data while surfing.
Data that needs to be collected, is a value of element that gets clicked, which is catched by eventListener for click and inserted to local variable I have added to the page.

This all works fine, except for the time where the element that gets clicked, is the actual button that contains a link that redirects page and changes the DOM.

My best guess is that at the same moment, the click, my JavaScript script that stores the variable, my JavaScript script that retrieves the variable, and the page redirect, all almost happen at the same time, suspecting that the change of the DOM happens before the retrieving of the variable, thus canceling any of my efforts to get that data.

This is the code:

```
from selenium.common import TimeoutException, WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

class Main:
def __init__(self, page_url):
    self.__driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.__element_list = []
    self.__page_url = page_url

def start(self):
    program_return = []

    self.__driver.get(self.__page_url)
    event_js = '''
    var array_events = []

    var registerOuterHtml = (e) => {
        array_events.push(e.target.outerHTML)
        window.array_events = array_events
        }
    var registerUrl = (e) => {
        array_events.push(document.documentElement.outerHTML)
        }

    getElementHtml = document.addEventListener("click", registerOuterHtml, true)
    getDOMHtml = document.addEventListener("click", registerUrl, true)
    '''
    return_js = '''return window.array_events'''
    self.__driver.set_script_timeout(10000)
    self.__driver.execute_script(event_js)
    try:
        for _ in range(800):
            if array_events := self.__driver.execute_script(return_js):
                if array_events[-2:] not in program_return:
                    program_return.append(array_events[-2:])
            else:
                try:
                    WebDriverWait(self.__driver, 0.1).until(
                        lambda driver: self.__driver.current_url != self.__page_url)
                except TimeoutException:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.__page_url = self.__driver.current_url
                    self.__driver.execute_script(event_js)
    except WebDriverException:
        pass
    finally:
        print(len(program_return))  # should print total number of clicks made.
```

To test it out, call it like this:

```
Main('any url you wish').start()
```

And after clicking, and should at least click a button which changes the page, you can close the window manually and check the results.

Please indent the functions of the class a tab to the right, I can't format it here for the sake of my life!

Any idea or ideally a solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Overall question---Taking for granted that variable persistence between different pages is not possible, **How can I get the value of that variable that gets set on the time of click, before the page changes, from the same click action?** (Maybe delay whole page...??)

Comment: You would need something event driven for this (probably not Python)

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically you can get some global data before a navigation like:

```
data = driver.execute_async_script("""
  let [resolve] = arguments
  window.unload = () => resolve(window.some_global_data)
""")
```

but it's likely to timeout ... Puppeteer / Playwright are better suited to things like this. There are python ports of them you might try.

Comment: This answer is not explained and/or wrong, I don't understand it.

Comment: window.unload fires before a navigation. resolve is the "callback". window.some_global_data is some data that you attached to window previously so it can be accessed globally.